# Как использовать Figma для Python?

Tags: python, gui, figma

Вопрос возможно немного нестандартный. Можно ли использовать Figma для Python? И есть ли хорошие конструкторы GUI для Python (помимо Qt Designer)?

Comment: Ну, как конструктор `tkinter` довольно неплох. Особенно, если связать с `ttk` и `ttkthemes` + научиться создавать свои темы на `tcl`

Comment: А TKinter можно использовать для Android приложений?

Comment: На сколько знаю - нет. Для андроида подойдёт `kivy`

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!

Comment: Наткнулся на вот такую штуку: https://morioh.com/p/f5935b761f28

Есл правильно понял, то можно создавать интерфейсы для `tkinter` как в `figma`

Comment: Это то,  что нужно! Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: Да, вроде не за что) Правда там заморочки большие с установкой...

Comment: Попробую разобраться. Это не столь важно. Вы мне действительно очень помогли!

Comment: Скоро выйдет утилита kivymdbuilder, она позволит создавать приложения как в qtdesigner, и функционала в ней будет больше